# how to get the values from json file using http get call in angular 2?

Tags: angular

[image]i am trying to get the values from my json file using http get call but getting error..

this is my component.ts file

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MyListComponent} from "./service-list.component";

    @Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        template: `
        <country-list></country-list>
        `,

    })
    export class AppComponent {
    }
```

and this is another component

```
import {Component , OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {CountryService} from "./country.service";
import {Country} from "./country";


@Component({
   selector: "country-list",
   template: ` List of Countries<br>
   <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let countrie of countries">{{ countrie.name }}</li>
   </ul>
   `,
   providers: [CountryService]
})

export class MyListComponent implements OnInit {
   contacts
   constructor(private _countryService: CountryService) {}

   ngOnInit(){
      this._countryService.getContacts()
      .subscribe(contacts => this.contacts = contacts)
   }
}
```

and this is my services file

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http , Response} from  '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Injectable()
export class CountryService {
    constructor(private http:Http){}
   getContacts() {
    return this.http.get('app/contacts.json')
     .map((res: Response)=> res.json())

   }
}
```

i am new to the angular 2 please help me

Comment: is there any error you are getting ?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a problem with http or your json file

Comment: Can you tell what error you are getting? and check your json file path, is correct or not.

Comment: in your subscribe you're setting `this.contacts = contacts` but then in your view you use countries. (I'm guessing it should be contacts).

Comment: have you added `MyListComponent` in your `@ngModule` declaration ?

Comment: Can you show your module configuration? If you are using older angular it looks like you havent specified directive since AppComponent can not recognise MyListComponent

Comment: You might have forgotten to import `MyListComponent ` in your `AppModule`